# What is the least upper bound on the number of pairs of disjoint subsets of a binary step-order set S whose sums differ by 1?

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

Define a binary step-order set as a finite set S of positive integers s<sub>i</sub>, i = 0 to n-1, where s<sub>i</sub> ≡ 2<sup>i</sup> (mod 2<sup>i+1</sup>) for each i from 0 to n-1. So, i is the power of 2 appearing in the prime factorization of s<sub>i</sub>. It’s elementary that binary step-order sets have distinct subset sums.

What is the least upper bound on the number of pairs of disjoint subsets of an n-element binary step-order set S whose sums differ by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is F<sub>n+1</sub>, where {F<sub>i</sub>} is the Fibonacci sequence.

Lemma – Let S be a binary step-order set with n elements. For any positive integer k, F<sub>n+1</sub> is an upper bound for the number of pairs of disjoint subsets of S whose sums differ by k, where {F<sub>i</sub>} is the Fibonacci sequence.

Proceeding by math induction, first prove the cases n = 1 and n = 2. For n = 1, the only possible pair of disjoint subsets is (S, φ); thus, F<sub>2</sub> = 1 is an upper bound for the number of pairs of disjoint subsets with sums differing by k.

For n ≥ 2, observe that finding a pair of disjoint subsets whose sums differ by k is equivalent to finding an n-tuple of coefficients **d** ∊ {-1, 0, 1}<sup>n</sup> such that ∑ d<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i</sub> = k – the elements of the higher-sum subset have coefficients 1, the elements of the lower-sum subset (if any – this may be φ) have coefficients -1, and the elements in neither subset have coefficients 0.

For n = 2, we have s<sub>0</sub> odd and s<sub>1</sub> even. So, there are two cases; s<sub>0</sub> > s<sub>1</sub> and s<sub>0</sub> < s<sub>1</sub>.
For s<sub>0</sub> > s<sub>1</sub>, the only possible coefficient ordered pairs d are (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1) and (1, 1); otherwise ∑ d<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i</sub> is not positive. Furthermore, these all yield distinct values of ∑ d<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i</sub>, because s<sub>0</sub> + s<sub>1</sub> > s<sub>0</sub> > s<sub>1</sub>, and because s<sub>1</sub> ≠ s<sub>0</sub> – s<sub>1</sub> because the former is even and the latter is odd. So, in this case, 1 is an upper bound for the number of disjoint subset pairs whose sums differ by k.
For s<sub>1</sub> > s<sub>0</sub>, the only possible coefficient ordered pairs d are (1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 1) and (1, 1); otherwise ∑ d<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i</sub> is not positive. We have s<sub>0</sub> + s<sub>1</sub> > s<sub>1</sub> > s<sub>0</sub>, so the only possible way to have ∑ d<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i</sub> = k for two distinct **d** is if s<sub>0</sub> = s<sub>1</sub> – s<sub>0</sub>; i.e., s<sub>1</sub> = 2s<sub>0</sub>.  So, in this case, F<sub>3</sub> = 2 is an upper bound for this case and the general n = 2 case of the number of disjoint subset pairs whose sums differ by k.

Now, assume that the lemma is true for all positive integers from 1 through n ≥ 2. Consider an n+1 element binary step-order set S<sub>n+1</sub>. Let S<sub>n</sub> be the n-element set obtained by omitting the odd element of S<sub>n+1</sub> and dividing all the other elements by 2 – clearly S<sub>n</sub> is a binary step-order set. Let S<sub>n-1</sub> be the n-1 element set obtained by omitting the odd element of S<sub>n</sub> and dividing all the other elements by 2 – clearly S<sub>n-1</sub> is also a binary step-order set. So s<sub>n,i</sub> = s<sub>n+1,i+1</sub> / 2 and s<sub>n-1,i</sub> = s<sub>n,i+1</sub> / 2.

Consider the case where k is even. The coefficient of s<sub>n+1,0</sub> must be 0 for any **d** in the solution set; otherwise ∑ d<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i</sub> is odd and ≠ k.  Each solution **d** = (0, d<sub>n+1,1</sub>, …, d<sub>n+1,n</sub>) corresponds to a solution d<sub>n</sub> for k/2 in S<sub>n</sub> via bijection, where d<sub>n,i</sub> = d<sub>n+1,i</sub> for i = 0 through n – 1. So, F<sub>n+1</sub> is an upper bound for the number of disjoint subset pairs of S<sub>n+1</sub> whose sums differ by an even k.

Consider the case where k is odd. The coefficient d<sub>n+1,0</sub> of s<sub>n+1,0</sub> must be either 1 or -1 for any **d** in the solution set; otherwise ∑ d<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i</sub> is even and ≠ k.  Now, for both of k and s<sub>n+1,0</sub>, we have cases ≡ 1 (mod 4) and ≡ 3 (mod 4); as a consequence, exactly one of k + s<sub>n+1,0</sub> and k - s<sub>n+1,0</sub> is ≡ 2 (mod 4), and the other is ≡ 0 (mod 4).  Say k + s<sub>n+1,0</sub> ≡ 0 (mod 4), and k - s<sub>n+1,0</sub> ≡ 2 (mod 4); the other case is similar & will be omitted.

Each solution **d** = (1, d<sub>n+1,1</sub>, …, d<sub>n+1,n</sub>) corresponds to a solution **d<sub>n</sub>** for |( k - s<sub>n+1,0</sub>)/2| in S<sub>n</sub> via bijection, where

-If k > s<sub>n+1,0</sub>, d<sub>n,i</sub> = d<sub>n+1,i+1</sub> for i = 0 through n – 1.

-If k < s<sub>n+1,0</sub>, d<sub>n,i</sub> = -d<sub>n+1,i+1</sub> for i = 0 through n – 1.

So, F<sub>n+1</sub> is an upper bound for the number of disjoint subset pairs of S<sub>n+1</sub> whose sums differ by k with d<sub>n+1,0</sub> = 1.

Consider the solutions **d** where d<sub>n+1,0</sub> = -1.  We have ∑ d<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i</sub> = k, so ∑ d<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i</sub> + s<sub>n+1,0</sub> ≡ 0 (mod 4). Hence, for the ordered n+1 tuple **d’** where d’<sub>n+1,0</sub> = 0 and d’<sub>n+1,i</sub> = d<sub>n+1,i</sub> for i = 1 through n, we have   ∑ d’<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i</sub> ≡ 0 (mod 4). Therefore, d’<sub>n+1,1</sub> = d<sub>n+1,1</sub> = 0; otherwise ∑ d’<sub>i</sub>s<sub>i</sub> ≡ 2 (mod 4).  Each solution **d** = (-1, 0, d<sub>n+1,2</sub>, …, d<sub>n+1,n</sub>) corresponds to a solution d<sub>n-1</sub> for( k + s<sub>n+1,0</sub>)/4 in S<sub>n-1</sub> via bijection, where d<sub>n-1,i</sub> = d<sub>n+1,i+2</sub> for i = 0 through n – 2. So, F<sub>n</sub> is an upper bound for the number of disjoint subset pairs of S<sub>n+1</sub> whose sums differ by k with d<sub>n+1,0</sub> = -1. As we have exhausted the two cases for d<sub>n+1,0</sub>, F<sub>n+2</sub> = F<sub>n+1</sub> + F<sub>n</sub> is an upper bound for the total number of disjoint subset pairs of S<sub>n+1</sub> whose sums differ by an odd k, or any positive integer k./

Applying the lemma to k = 1, conclude that F<sub>n+1</sub> is an upper bound on the number of pairs of disjoint subsets of an n-element binary step-order set S whose sums differ by 1. To show that F<sub>n+1</sub> is the least upper bound, we’ll construct a sequence of binary step-order sets where this upper bound is realized.

Let S<sub>1</sub> = {1}, S<sub>2</sub> = {1,2}, and S<sub>3</sub> = {3,2,4}. Given S<sub>n</sub> for n ≥ 2, S<sub>n+1</sub> is constructed by setting s<sub>n+1,0</sub> = 3, and s<sub>n+1,i</sub> = 2s<sub>n,i-1</sub>for i = 1 to n. (The set elements are listed in the order of increasing power of 2 in the prime factorization of the element.) There are 2 solutions for **d** for S<sub>2</sub>; namely (1,0) and (-1,1). There are 3 solutions for **d** for S<sub>3</sub>; namely (1,-1,0), (1,1,-1) and (-1,0,1). (Because the 0 term of the sum is either 3 or -3, the subtotal of the other terms must be either -2 or 4 to have the sum of 1.) The F<sub>n+2</sub> solutions for S<sub>n+1</sub> are:

-The F<sub>n+1</sub> n+1 tuples d defined by setting d<sub>n+1,0</sub> = 1 and  d<sub>n+1,i</sub> = -d<sub>n,i-1</sub> for i = 1 to n from all the solutions d<sub>n</sub> for S<sub>n</sub>; plus

-The F<sub>n</sub> n+1 tuples d defined by setting d<sub>n+1,0</sub> = -1, d<sub>n+1,1</sub> = 0 and  d<sub>n+1,i</sub> = d<sub>n-1,i-1</sub> for i = 1 to n from all the solutions d<sub>n-1</sub> for S<sub>n-1</sub>.

Note: I couldn't work out fully how to do sigma notation; hopefully the sum limits are clearly implied.

Comment: For things like sigma notation, try latex (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-should-go-in-the-math-stackexchange-faq/117#117)

Comment: @Cam, thanks. I especially like the tip to look for a question with markup similar to what you want to use, right-click & select show source.